# Making a time comparitor for a project

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

I made a project called marathon i ask the user for a name , starting hour,starting, minute, starting second , end hour, end minute and end second. As of right now it tells name start and end times and duration Hours:Min:Sec my issue is I don't know how to get a comparitor set up to take those duration times and make them into a sorted list(so runners with lowest time at the top and slowest at the bottom).

this is main

```
/* @author maxkidd
 * 
 * Marathon takes name start time and end time and saves it in a collection also 
 * calculates duration of runners race
 */


    package marathon;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.InputMismatchException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.*;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public class Marathon {


    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );

        // Create a List of Runners







    int response = 0;

            while(response != -1) {


                List<Runner> list = new ArrayList<Runner>();
        // Prompt the user to enter runners
        // while loop here
        //while (!response.equals("N"))
        // After user enters each runner
        // Create a runner object



        try {
            System.out.println("Enter Runner name");

            String name= input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter starting hour ");
        int start_hours = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter starting minute ");
        int start_mins = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter starting second ");
         int start_seconds = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter ending hour ");
        int end_hours = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter ending minute");
        int end_mins = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter ending second ");
        int end_seconds = input.nextInt();




        // Calculate Duration
        int duration = ((end_hours*3600+end_mins*60+end_seconds)
                      -(start_hours*3600+start_mins*60+start_seconds))/3600;


        int durationM = ((end_mins*60+end_seconds)
                  -(start_mins*60+start_seconds))/60;

        int durationS= (end_seconds
                  -start_seconds);

        int place = 1;



        // int durationS = durationM/60;

        Runner runner = new Runner(

                place, name,
                start_hours,
                start_mins,
                start_seconds,
                end_hours,
                end_mins,
                end_seconds,
                duration,
                durationM,
                durationS
                );



        // Add runner to the list
        list.add(runner);





        // Output the List of Runners
        System.out.printf("NAME START:TIME  END:TIME   DURATION   %n");

        // Loop through the list of runners and print them out
        for (Runner r : list) {
            System.out.printf("%s     ", r.getName());
            r.displayStartTime();
            r.displayEndTime();
            r.displayduration();
            System.out.printf(" %n");
        }
        System.out.print("If you would like to stop enter -1 or add another runner press 1 ");
         response = input.nextInt();

         System.out.printf(" Response is %d " , response);

    } catch(InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number next time please! ");

    }
            }   
    }
}
```

This is the second class that gives main its r.displays

```
package marathon;

public class Runner {

    private String name;
    private int StartHours;
    private int StartMins;
    private int StartSeconds;
    private int EndHours;
    private int EndMins;
    private int EndSeconds;
    private int Duration;
    private int DurationHours;
    private int DurationMinutes;
    private int durationSeconds;
    private int place;

    public Runner(
            int place,
            String name,
            int StartHours,
            int StartMins,
            int StartSeconds,
            int EndHours,
            int EndMins,
            int EndSeconds,
            int DurationHours, 
            int DurationMinutes, 
            int durationSeconds) {


        this.name = name;
        this.StartHours = StartHours;
        this.StartMins = StartMins;
        this.StartSeconds = StartSeconds;
        this.EndHours = EndHours;
        this.EndMins = EndMins;
        this.EndSeconds = EndSeconds;
        this.DurationHours = DurationHours;
        this.DurationMinutes = DurationMinutes;
        this.durationSeconds = durationSeconds;
    }

    public void displayduration() {
        System.out.printf("%d Hour(s):%d Minute(s):%d Second(s) ", DurationHours,DurationMinutes, durationSeconds);
    }



    public void displayStartTime() {
        System.out.printf("%d:%d:%d     ", StartHours,StartMins,StartSeconds);
    }

    public void displayEndTime() {
        System.out.printf("%d:%d:%d     ", EndHours, EndMins, EndSeconds);
    }

    public void setDuration(int Duration) {
        this.Duration = Duration;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return this.Duration;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(int place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly encourage the use of `Duration` and (at least) `LocalTime` from the `java.time` API

Answer (score 1):

you need to make your `Runner` object *comparable* like this

```
class Runner implements Comparable<Runner>{
    ....

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Author other){
        // compareTo should return < 0 if this is supposed to be
        // less than other, > 0 if this is supposed to be greater than
        // other and 0 if they are supposed to be equal
        if (this.hours > other.getHours())
            return 1;
        else if (this.hours < other.getHours())
            return -1;
        else {
            if (this.minutes > other.getMinutes())
                return 1;
            else if (this.minutes > other.getMinutes())
                    return -1;
            else {
                if (this.seconds > other.getSeconds())
                    return 1;
                else if (this.seconds > other.getSeconds())
                    return -1;
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

than you can sort any list of Runners with the built in function at utils

Comment: still, storing minutes, seconds and hours separately is a bad idea. It makes the code too complicated, instead we should just use LocalTime.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the idea of MadProgrammer and reworked the Runner class a bit so it actually used Duration. Also, I reworked the Marathon class to use a TreeSet which sorts automatically by the runner's duration.

## Marathon

```
/* @author maxkidd
 *
 * Marathon takes name start time and end time and saves it in a collection also
 * calculates duration of runners race
 */

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Marathon {

    @SuppressWarnings({"resource", "unused"})
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Create a List of Runners
        int response = 0;

        while (response != -1) {
            Set<Runner> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Runner::getDuration));
            // Prompt the user to enter runners
            // while loop here
            //while (!response.equals("N"))
            // After user enters each runner
            // Create a runner object

            try {
                System.out.println("Enter Runner name");

                String name = input.next();

                System.out.print("Enter starting hour ");
                int start_hours = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter starting minute ");
                int start_mins = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter starting second ");
                int start_seconds = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter ending hour ");
                int end_hours = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter ending minute");
                int end_mins = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter ending second ");
                int end_seconds = input.nextInt();

                LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.of(start_hours, start_mins, start_seconds);
                LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.of(end_hours, end_mins, end_seconds);
                Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, endTime);

                int place = 1;

                Runner runner = new Runner(
                        place,
                        name,
                        startTime,
                        endTime,
                        duration
                );

                set.add(runner);

                // Output the Set of Runners
                System.out.printf("NAME START:TIME  END:TIME   DURATION   %n");

                // Loop through the Set of runners and print them out
                for (Runner r : set) {
                    System.out.printf("%s     ", r.getName());
                    r.displayStartTime();
                    r.displayEndTime();
                    r.displayduration();
                    System.out.printf(" %n");
                }
                System.out.print("If you would like to stop enter -1 or add another runner press 1 ");
                response = input.nextInt();

                System.out.printf(" Response is %d ", response);

            } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
                System.out.print("Enter a number next time please! ");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Runner

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Runner {

    private String name;
    private final LocalTime startTime;
    private final LocalTime endTime;
    private final Duration duration;
    private int place;

    public Runner(int place, String name, LocalTime startTime, LocalTime endTime, Duration duration) {
        this.place = place;
        this.name = name;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void displayduration() {
        System.out.printf("%d Hour(s):%d Minute(s):%d Second(s) ", duration.get(ChronoUnit.HOURS), 
                          duration.get(ChronoUnit.MINUTES), duration.get(ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
    }

    public void displayStartTime() {
        System.out.printf("%d:%d:%d     ", startTime.getHour(),
                startTime.getMinute(), startTime.getSecond());
    }

    public void displayEndTime() {
        System.out.printf("%d:%d:%d     ", endTime.getHour(),
                          endTime.getMinute(), endTime.getSecond());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public LocalTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public LocalTime getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public int getPlace() {
        return place;
    }
}
```